# LaTeX Syntax Highlighting in Google Drive

Tags: online

I like the LaTeX syntax highlighting in emacs through AUCTeX, but for various reasons like to write my LaTeX documents in Google Drive. I wanted to write a Google Script to do LaTeX syntax highlighting directly in my Google Drive LaTeX documents.

I've looked around online to see if people have attempted this. I've seen the source code for latex-lab, which is a standalone online editor, that reads from Google Drive. I would prefer writing directly in Google Drive itself. The code uses codemirror, and has a latexparser JavaScript that seems like it shouldn't be too painful to port to Google Script.

My main question is: does this sound feasible? I don't want to dedicate the time if it's just going to turn out too slow, or if someone has already written such a script.

Comment: This question does not fall under the scope of TeX.SX, as it is about coding some webservice. Maybe it is better suited for StackOverflow.

Comment: You could try to include [Google Code Prettify](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/). This is the one also used on all StackExchange sites.

Comment: I suggest you try [Drive Notepad](https://drivenotepad.appspot.com). Chrome Web Store app but works in Firefox too. It can edit and syntax highlight all sorts of languages, including LaTeX. It integrates nicely into Google Drive.

Comment: @marczellm In Firefox I have to click on “Launch App”, I guess.

Comment: @Speravir Yep :) After you've granted the permissions to Drive Notepad, it will associate itself with the supported file formats in Google Drive online, and appear in the "Open with..." menu too.